# Error using Rcpp::Nullable with RcppArmadillo types

Tags: rcpp

I'm using RcppArmadillo in my R package and I would like to use the Rcpp::Nullable in the parameter list.

```
NumericVector d_snb(NumericVector& x,
                Nullable<arma::mat> size_param = R_NilValue,
                const int& infinite = 100000, const bool& log_v = false)
```

This gives an error like:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘packagex’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...): unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/packagex/libs/packagex.so': dlopen(/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/packagex/libs/packagex.so, 6): 
Symbol not found: __Z5d_snbRN4Rcpp6VectorILi14ENS_15PreserveStorageEEENS_8NullableIS2_EES5_S5_RKiRKb
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/packagex/libs/packagex.so
Expected in: flat namespace in /usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/packagex/libs/packagex.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
```

The only possible solution right now seems to get the parameter as NumericVector and then get contents and then cast it into Armadillo types.

```
NumericVector d_snb(NumericVector& x,
                Nullable<NumericVector> size_param = R_NilValue ...)
{
...

  if(size_param.isNotNull()) {
    arma::mat test(NumericVector(size_param));
    param_check++;
  }
...
}
```

This gives a warning:

```
d_snb.cpp:36:21: warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
  arma::mat test(NumericVector(size_param));
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
d_snb.cpp:36:22: note: add a pair of parentheses to declare a variable
  arma::mat test(NumericVector(size_param));
                 ^
                 (                        )
1 warning generated.
```

What's the best way to go about this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `Rcpp::Nullable<>` works only around `SEXP`-based Rcpp types.

So you have to do the two-step procedure you found. But I think you can do one simpler:  `arma::mat test = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(size_param);`

Here is a complete example which compiles (but does 'nothing'):

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void d_snb(Rcpp::NumericVector& x,
           Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::NumericVector> size_param = R_NilValue) {

  if (size_param.isNotNull()) {
    arma::vec test = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(size_param);
    test.print("vector");
  }
  Rcpp::Rcout << x << std::endl;

}
```

And a quick demo:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/so44102346.cpp")
R> d_snb(c(1,2,3))
1 2 3
R> d_snb(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))
vector
   4.0000
   5.0000
   6.0000
1 2 3
R>
```

Comment: Good solution. But is it possible to pass Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::NumericVector> by reference. Probably the optional parameter will be a large vector If I use it. So I do not want to make a copy